# Angular 2: when i change a variable in a promise.than in ngOnInit the view doesn't refresh

Tags: angular, angular-promise, nativescript

I created a short example of an Angular 2 application built with `NativeScript`, what I expect is the variable `foo` to be "foo" at the beginning, then the `ngOnInit()` first change it to "bar" and then the promise return and I should see "foobar" in the Label, but instead I see "bar".

The execution is as expected as I can see in the logs:

```
JS: afterBar
JS: promise new
JS: promise than
```

component.ts

```
foo:String="foo";

ngOnInit() {
    this.foo = "bar";
    console.log("afterBar");

    var promise = new Promise((resolve)=>{
        resolve(42);
        console.log("promise new");
    });

    promise.then(x=> {
        this.foo="foobar";
        console.log("promise than");
    });
}
```

The app view:

```
<Label [text]='foo'></Label>
```

how can I change the Label text in a promise an see it "refreshing" into the app view?

**SOLVED:**

I solved the problem by forcing an update

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
    [...]
constructor(
    [...],
    private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {       
}

[...]
this.ref.detectChanges();
```

Comment: How does `Label` look like?

Comment: `<Label [text]='foo'></Label>`

Comment: That's the app components view according to your question. Please post the code of the label component.

Comment: try using import `{NgZone} from "@angular/core";`

 `constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone){}`

`this._ngZone.run(() => {
                this.foo="foobar";
});`

Comment: there is no code for the label component. i declared a variable and i used the angular binding `[text]='foo'` to print the string in the view

Comment: @HabibKazemi this is the code but is not working
`promise.then(x=> {
   this.foo="foobar";
   this._ngZone.run(() => { this.foo="xxxxx"; });
   console.log("promise than");
  });
`

Comment: For me `<label text="foobar"></label>` (plain HTML without any Angular) also doesn't show anything in the browser, therefore it's expected that `<Label [text]='foo'></Label>` doesn't. See @Thyagu's answer.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer are you using a mobile app with NativeScript? because a NativeScript label is not an HTML label

Comment: @AndreaVeronesi I see. Didn't know.